# Парсинг с Jsoup и заполнение в таблицу

Tags: android, select, jsoup

Доброго времени суток. Мозг уже сломал, не могу разобраться как правильно парсить данный класс страницы и правильно загнать это всё в TableRow:

```
<div id="contrighta" class="contrighta">
<h1>Some label</h1><br>

<table>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
       <th width="420" align="left" valign="top">News Title</th>
       <th width="70 " align="left" valign="top">Date</th>
       <th width="120" align="left" valign="top">News Category</th>
       <th width="100" align="left" valign="top">Language</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="bodyblack">
            <a href="some_link">Some text</a></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some data</td>            
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some people</td> 
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some language</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="bodyblack">
            <a href="some_link">Some text</a></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some data</td>            
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some people</td> 
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some language</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="bodyblack">
            <a href="some_link">Some text</a></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some data</td>            
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some people</td> 
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some language</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="bodyblack">
            <a href="some_link">Some text</a></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some data</td>            
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some people</td> 
             <td align="left" valign="top" nowrap="">Some language</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

По сути я добрался до текста, но правильно всё же было бы сгруппировать эту кучу, и ещё каким-то образом вывести в TableRow

```
if (doc != null) {
            Elements tableRows = doc.getElementsByClass("contrighta")
                    .select("tr");
            Iterator<Element> rowIterator = tableRows.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Element tableRow = rowIterator.next();
                //<td align="left" valign="top" class="bodyblack"><a href="some_link">Some text</a></td>
                Elements data = tableRow.select("td");
                //Log.d("NewsFragment", "" + data);
                for (Element link : data) {
                    Log.d("Return: ", "" + link.text());
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- В вёрстке не хватало одного закрывающего div'а
- добавил на всякий пожарный случай в вёрстку html/head/body
- для удобства положил данные ячеек в мапы
- при обходе строк, пропустил строку с заголовками, т.к. в ней не содержались данные

  ```
  String html = "<html>" +
          "<head></head>" +
          "<body>" +
          "<div id=\"contrighta\" class=\"contrighta\">\n" +
          "<h1>Some label</h1><br>\n" +
          "<table>\n" +
          "    <tbody>\n" +
          "    <tr>\n" +
          "       <th width=\"420\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">News Title</th>\n" +
          "       <th width=\"70 \" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">Date</th>\n" +
          "       <th width=\"120\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">News Category</th>\n" +
          "       <th width=\"100\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">Language</th>\n" +
          "    </tr>\n" +
          "    <tr>\n" +
          "        <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" class=\"bodyblack\">\n" +
          "            <a href=\"some_link\">Some text</a></td>\n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some data</td>            \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some people</td> \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some language</td>\n" +
          "    </tr>\n" +
          "    <tr>\n" +
          "        <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" class=\"bodyblack\">\n" +
          "            <a href=\"some_link\">Some text</a></td>\n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some data</td>            \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some people</td> \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some language</td>\n" +
          "    </tr>\n" +
          "    <tr>\n" +
          "        <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" class=\"bodyblack\">\n" +
          "            <a href=\"some_link\">Some text</a></td>\n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some data</td>            \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some people</td> \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some language</td>\n" +
          "    </tr>\n" +
          "    <tr>\n" +
          "        <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" class=\"bodyblack\">\n" +
          "            <a href=\"some_link\">Some text</a></td>\n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some data</td>            \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some people</td> \n" +
          "             <td align=\"left\" valign=\"top\" nowrap=\"\">Some language</td>\n" +
          "    </tr>\n" +
          "    </tbody>\n" +
          "</table>" +
          "</div>" +
          "</body>" +
          "</html>";

  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  List<HashMap<String,String>> table = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  for(Element row: doc.select("div#contrighta table tr")){
      Elements cells = row.select("td");
      if(cells.size()==0) continue;

      HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

      map.put("text", cells.get(0).text());
      map.put("data", cells.get(1).text());
      map.put("people", cells.get(2).text());
      map.put("language", cells.get(3).text());

      table.add(map);
  }

  for(Map<String,String> map:table){
      Log.i("JSOUP/Data","text = " + map.get("text"));
      Log.i("JSOUP/Data","data = " + map.get("data"));
      Log.i("JSOUP/Data","people = " + map.get("people"));
      Log.i("JSOUP/Data","language = " + map.get("language")+"\n");

  }
  ```

Для того чтобы включить заголовки в список с данными нужно:

- заменить извлечение всех нод TD из строки( *row.select("td")* ) на извлечение всех дочерних ( *row.children()* )
- элементов убрать условие в котором пропускается итерация в строке без
  TD if(cells.size()==0) continue;

Было:

```
        Elements cells = row.select("td");
        if(cells.size()==0) continue;
```

Стало:

```
        Elements cells = row.children();
```